# Randomize transformation of instanced objects (animation node)

Tags: animation-nodes

[image]

Hello!

I have some cubes instanced and animated by a wiggle node.

[image]

Every element is moving the same way and I want to randomize the motion of each element.

My plan was to get a value for each element that I could use to randomize the wiggle seed for each object.

Is this possible? And if it is, I'll need some help!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Blender Stack Exchange. Yes, it is possible. You have to create a list of random rotation that has length same as the number of instance objects. You can generate that list from the Number Wiggle node or you can also you the Euler Wiggle node as well.